# Error when running "npx create-react-app myfirstreact"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu

`sudo npx create-react-app myfirstreact`. I have attempted doing "sudo chown -R 1001:1002 "/root/.npm" many times, and have uninstalled and reinstalled node and npm multiple times.

```
Creating a new React app in /home/cade_heinb/myfirstreact.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
glob error { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs']
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/root/.npm/_logs' }
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /root/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/05/0b/bcb6626a692a9538a4a4cafe8f85652b36227ca5a893b60ef299d729d69e
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 1001:1002 "/root/.npm"
Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting myfirstreact/ from /home/cade_heinb
Done.
```

Comment: You should not be running `npx` in sudo mode. That's just asking for trouble. But the error it seems has to do with how you installed node and npm. Likely also with sudo which is not great

Comment: It doesn't allow me to install npm or node without sudo. However I was able to run npx in non-sudo mode and that seemed to fix the errors from spitting out. But now the task just freezes.